# How to get redefining YYSTYPE work properly?

Tags: yacc, lex

As far as I know, if I need to return tokens which is not of integer types (by default) in lex, I have to redefine YYSTYPE to give it the capability to do so.

But I'm getting some strange errors as follows.

I have a file called symbols.h where I put the struct I need, and it's included by both the .l file (lex) and .y file (yacc)

```
struct type
{
    int val;
    double dval;
    bool bval; 
    string* sval;
    idData* iddata;
    int type;
};

// typedef type YYSTYPE;
// #define YYSTYPE type
```

If I use #define, I'm getting something like this:

```
duplicate symbol __Z13yylex_destroyv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-7b46a5.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-64e257.o
```

together with a linking error

and for typedef, it shows me this:

```
In file included from scanner.l:6:
./y.tab.hpp:146:13: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('int' vs 'type')
typedef int YYSTYPE;
            ^
./symbols.h:48:14: note: previous definition is here
typedef type YYSTYPE;
             ^
```

so how do I do to get self-defined-YYSTYPE work properly?

**EDIT:**

the declaration part of my parser.y:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "symbols.h"
#include <string>
#include "lex.yy.cpp"
#define TRACE_FLAG 1
#define trace(t) if (TRACE_FLAG) cout << "TRACE => " << t <<endl;
using namespace std;

void yyerror(string s);

vector<SymbolTable> stbs;
idData* lookupAll(string s, bool ptr=false);

%}

/* tokens */
%token LESS_EQUAL GREATER_EQUAL EQUAL NOT_EQUAL AND OR ASSIGNMENT
%token BEGIN_LEX BREAK CASE CONST CONTINUE DO ELSE END EXIT FN FOR IF IN LOOP MODULE OF PRINT PRINTLN PROCEDURE READ RECORD REPEAT RETURN THEN TYPE USE UTIL VAR WHILE 
%token ARRAY BOOLEAN CHAR INTEGER REAL STRING

%token <sval> IDENTIFIER
%token <val> INT_CONST
%token <bval> BOOL_CONST
%token <dval> REAL_CONST  
%token <sval> STR_CONST

/* type declaration for non-terminal symbols */
%type <iddata> constant_value expression
%type <type> var_type

/* precedence */
%left OR
%left AND
%left '~'
%left '<' '>' LESS_EQUAL GREATER_EQUAL EQUAL NOT_EQUAL
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%nonassoc UMINUS 

/* start of the program */
%start program
```

for the scanner.l:

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "symbols.h"
#include "y.tab.hpp"
using namespace std;

#define LIST     strcat(buf,yytext)
#define SHOW_TOKEN 0
#define token(t) {LIST; if(SHOW_TOKEN) printf("<%s>\n",#t);}
#define tokenInteger(t,i) {LIST; if(SHOW_TOKEN) printf("<%s:%d>\n",t,i); }
#define tokenString(t,s) {LIST; if(SHOW_TOKEN) printf("<%s:%s>\n",t,s);}

#define MAX_LINE_LENG 256
int linenum = 1;
char buf[MAX_LINE_LENG];
string str;

%}

whitespace [ \t]+
digit [0-9]
letter [a-zA-Z]
identifier {letter}({digit}|{letter})*
integer [+-]?{digit}+
real [+-]?{digit}+"."{digit}+([Ee][+-]{digit}+)?

%x COMMENT_MODULA
%x COMMENT_C
%x STR
```

contents of symbols.h:

```
#ifndef SYMBOLS_H
#define SYMBOLS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum variable_type{
    t_INT,
    t_BOOL,
    t_REAL,
    t_STR,
    t_ARRAY,
    t_VOID
};

struct idData
{
    int type = t_VOID;                      // enum type

    /* id value */
    int val = 0;                            // integer
    bool bval = false;                      // boolean
    double dval = 0;                        // float
    string* sval = new string("");          // string
    vector<idData> aval;                    // array
    int arr_type = t_VOID;                  // enum type

    idData();
    idData(int type);
};

void print_id(idData id);

struct type
{
    int val;
    double dval;
    bool bval; 
    string* sval;
    idData* iddata;
    int type;
};

// typedef type YYSTYPE;
#define YYSTYPE type

class SymbolTable {
private:
        map<string, idData> symbols;
public:
        idData* lookup(string s,  bool ptr);
        bool insert(string s, idData value);
        idData* get_id_ptr(string s);
        int dump(string function_name);
};

#endif
```

and finally the makefile: (I'm doing it on a Mac, BTW.)

```
TARGET = parser
LEX = flex
YACC = yacc
YACCFLAG = -d
CXX = g++
CXXFLAG = -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET)

y.tab.cpp: parser.y
    $(YACC) $(YACCFLAG) -o $@ $^

lex.yy.cpp: scanner.l
    $(LEX) -o $@ $^

$(TARGET): lex.yy.cpp y.tab.cpp symbols.cpp symbols.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAG) lex.yy.cpp y.tab.cpp symbols.cpp -o $@ -ll -ly

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) lex.yy.cpp y.tab.*
```

yacc is linked to bison on macOS by default, and I've tried with byacc, getting basically the same result.

error message:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register lex.yy.cpp y.tab.cpp symbols.cpp -o parser -ll -ly
duplicate symbol __Z13yylex_destroyv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z5yylexv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z10yyget_textv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z9yyget_outv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z12yyget_linenov in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z8yyget_inv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z11yyget_debugv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z10yyget_lengv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z18yypop_buffer_statev in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z6yyfreePv in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _yytext in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _yyout in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _str in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _yylineno in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _yyin in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z9yyreallocPvm in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _linenum in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z7yyallocm in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z14yy_scan_bufferPcm in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z12yyset_linenoi in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z11yyset_debugi in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z13yy_scan_bytesPKci in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z16yy_create_bufferP7__sFILEi in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _yy_flex_debug in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _yyleng in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol _buf in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z19yy_switch_to_bufferP15yy_buffer_state in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z15yy_flush_bufferP15yy_buffer_state in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z16yy_delete_bufferP15yy_buffer_state in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z19yypush_buffer_stateP15yy_buffer_state in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z14yy_scan_stringPKc in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z9yyset_outP7__sFILE in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z9yyrestartP7__sFILE in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
duplicate symbol __Z8yyset_inP7__sFILE in:
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/lex-51b52c.o
    /var/folders/50/dhxd49xd3f5c2rkvsdspk7r40000gn/T/y-7ea26f.o
ld: 34 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

[the structure of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw3g3.png)

Comment: Your first error doesn't appear to have anything to do with your definition of `YYSTYPE`. You'd need to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including how you build your project, for us to be able to tell you why `yylex_destroy` is defined twice.

Comment: It seems I don't have the permission to edit my post, so I'm putting my materials in the reply. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `yylex_destroy` the only duplicate symbol?

Comment: And you absolutely have the ability to edit your post, unless there is a pending edit by someone else.

Comment: Well it's my first time posting on stackoverflow and I missed the edit button lol I've put the full error message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is probably a better solution, since what you seem to be aiming at is a tagged union, and bison does have some features which allow for that. But in any case, your attempts fail for two different reasons:

1. The bison-generated header file includes `typedef int YYSTYPE` unless you `#define YYSTYPE`. (The `typedef` is guarded by `#ifndef YYSTYPE`.) User typedefs of `YYSTYPE` are not supported.
2. You compile the scanner and the parser independently. So if you *also* `#include "lex.yy.cpp"` into your parser, you end up compiling it twice into your project. Hence the duplicate symbol errors.

Comment: I've also tried with the union solution, like putting this one in parser.y %union {
 int val;
 double dval;
 bool bval; 
 string* sval;
 idData* iddata;
 int type;
} but the error says that it can't recognize string and idData?

Comment: @brothre: your `using namespace std;` hasn't yet been seen when `y.tab.hpp` has been included. You should get out of the habit of `using namespace std;` now before it gets you into more trouble. Use`std::` when that's what you mean, particularly in header files

Comment: (The declarations in a `%union` block are placed into the scanner header file, so they count as "particularly in header files").

Comment: Also, you need to make sure the `%union` block goes after the `%{…%}` block with the `#includes` it relies on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, I've done with the include problem; for the re-compiling issue, I'm told that I need to include lex.yy.cpp in my parser, so I don't have to compile it again when generating the executable? Or it's either include it or compile it?

Comment: @broth: yep one or the other. If you do both, you define everything twice, which is not allowed. Prefer separate compilation; it's better to get comfortable with that model if you intend to learn C++.